# Panel scrolling automatically

Tags: c#, checkbox, scroll

I have an `UserControl` and inside it I have some controls and one of these controls is a `CheckBox`. This `CheckBox` performs a `CheckedChanged` action that calls a method and this method sets some of the controls of the `Panel` to `Enabled` or `Visible`.

When I click to check the `CheckBox` the `Panel` where all these controls are inserted scrolls down automatically like the images below.

How could I stop the `Panel` scrolling down after checking the `CheckBox`?

[image]
Inicial position

[image]
Position after checking the CheckBox

The code is below

The CheckBox Action

```
private void usuarioMedicoCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                carregarMedicos();
            } else
            {
                medicos = null;
            }

            usuarioMedicoComboBox.Enabled = usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Checked;
            cadastrarMedicoButton.Enabled = usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Checked;
        }
```

Method carregarMedico

```
private void carregarMedicos()
        {
            processandoDados(true);

            ParseQuery<Classes.Medico> query = new ParseQuery<Classes.Medico>();

            query.OrderBy("nomeCompleto").FindAsync().ContinueWith(resultado => {
                if (resultado.IsCompleted && !resultado.IsFaulted)
                {
                    medicos = resultado.Result.ToList();

                    atualizarMedicosComboBoxDelegate atualizarMedicosComboBoxD = new atualizarMedicosComboBoxDelegate(atualizarMedicosComboBox);
                    this.Invoke(atualizarMedicosComboBoxD, new object[] { });
                } else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Houve um erro ao buscar os médicos", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                processandoDadosDelegate processandoDadosD = new processandoDadosDelegate(processandoDados);
                this.Invoke(processandoDadosD, new object[] { false });
            });
        }
```

Method atualizarMedicosComboBox

```
private void atualizarMedicosComboBox()
        {
            usuarioMedicoComboBox.Items.Clear();

            if (medicos != null && medicos.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach(Classes.Medico medico in medicos)
                {
                    usuarioMedicoComboBox.Items.Add(medico.nomeCompleto);
                }
            } else
            {
                usuarioMedicoComboBox.Items.Add("Não há médicos cadastrados");
            }
        }
```

Method processandoDados

```
private void processandoDados(bool acao)
        {
            if (acao)
            {
                nomeCompletoTextBox.Enabled = false;
                emailTextBox.Enabled = false;
                cpfMaskedTextBox.Enabled = false;
                selecionarFotoButton.Enabled = false;
                usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                usuarioMedicoComboBox.Enabled = false;
                cadastrarMedicoButton.Enabled = false;
                usuarioAdmCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                permissoesPacientesGroupBox.Enabled = false;
                permissoesMedicosGroupBox.Enabled = false;
                permissoesUsuariosGroupBox.Enabled = false;
                salvarUsuarioButton.Visible = false;
                salvarUsuarioProgressBar.Visible = true;
            } else
            {
                nomeCompletoTextBox.Enabled = true;
                emailTextBox.Enabled = true;
                cpfMaskedTextBox.Enabled = true;
                selecionarFotoButton.Enabled = true;
                usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Enabled = true;

                if (usuarioMedicoCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    usuarioMedicoComboBox.Enabled = true;
                    cadastrarMedicoButton.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    usuarioMedicoComboBox.Enabled = false;
                    cadastrarMedicoButton.Enabled = false;
                }

                usuarioAdmCheckBox.Enabled = true;
                salvarUsuarioButton.Visible = true;
                salvarUsuarioProgressBar.Visible = false;

                if(!usuarioAdmCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    permissoesPacientesGroupBox.Enabled = true;
                    permissoesMedicosGroupBox.Enabled = true;
                    permissoesUsuariosGroupBox.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing visible property of the button at the bottom of the panel, set the focus on that item. Try just to enable/disable that button instead.